# 2D Array outputting from left to right, then right to left. Can't seem to get the correct element

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have to output my 2D Array from left to right on even rows, and from right to left on odd rows. I've done that and that isn't the problem. The problem is I am getting really confused when I try to access an element inside the 2D array because now the odd rows are reversed.

Here is my current output with the output being from left to right then right to left:

```
0.5       0.62      0.35      0.6       0.5       
0.13      0.25      0.25      0.62      0.45      
0.65      0.85      0.2       0.2       0.8
```

Here is the output without making any changes to the output:

```
0.5       0.62      0.35      0.6       0.5       
0.45      0.62      0.25      0.25      0.13
0.65      0.85      0.2       0.2       0.8
```

I need to get the average of each 2 X 2, and then find out which is the weakest. I have done that, however the math doesn't seem to work out, and I am assuming it is because the elements on odd rows are reversed.

Here is my current output for finding the weakest:

```
0.5
0.45999999999999996
0.3625
0.3625
0.3625
0.3625
0.22499999999999998
0.22499999999999998
Weakest begins at (1, 2) with an average strength of 0.22499999999999998
```

Here is what the correct output should have an average strength of 0.3175:

```
Weakest begins at (1, 2) with an average strength of 0.3175
```

Finally here is my code for making each odd row output from right to left:

```
int k = 0;
        cd = new double[3][5];
        for(int i = 0; i<cd.length;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<cd[i].length;j++,k++)
                 cd[i][j]=gridArr[k];
        for(int i = 0; i < cd.length; i++){
            if(i%2==0)
                for(int j = 0; j < cd[i].length; j++)
                    System.out.print(String.format("%-10s" ,cd[i][j]));
            else
                for(int j = cd[i].length -1; j >= 0; j--)
                    System.out.print(String.format("%-10s" ,cd[i][j]));
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Here is the code to find the weakest 2 X 2:

```
double weakest = getAverage(0, 0, 0, 0);
    int weakestRow = 0;
    int weakestCol = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < cd.length-1; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < cd[0].length-1;col++){
            if(weakest > getAverage(row, row+1, col, col+1)) {
                weakest = getAverage(row, row+1, col, col+1);
                weakestRow = row;
                weakestCol = col;
            } System.out.println(weakest);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nWeakest begins at "
            +"("+weakestRow+", "+weakestCol+") with an average strength of "
            +weakest);
}
```

Any ideas? I've looked over this for hours and can't wrap my head around it...

**Edit:** getAverage is:

```
    double first = cd[startRow][startCol];
    double second = cd[endRow][startCol];
    double third = cd[startRow][endCol];
    double fourth = cd[endRow][endCol];
    return (first+second+third+fourth)/4;
```

Comment: could  you please give the implementation of your `getAverage` method ?

Comment: @XavierDelamotte getAverage is very plain `double first = cd[startRow][startCol];
        double second = cd[endRow][startCol];
        double third = cd[startRow][endCol];
        double fourth = cd[endRow][endCol];
        return (first+second+third+fourth)/4;`

Answer (score 0):

It's because your program is find the average of the square on the original array, not the one where you reverse the order of the odd rows.

Displaying the array has no effect.

What you shoudl do, is call your getWeakest method on an array where the odd rows has been reversed.

```
   oddRowReversedArray = new double[3][5];
   for(int i = 0; i < cd.length; i++){
        if(i%2==0)
            oddRowReversedArray[i] = cd[i]
        else
            for(int j = cd[i].length -1; j >= 0; j--)
                oddRowReversedArray[i][j] = cd[i][cd.length -1 -j]
    }
```

and then call getWeakest of this array.

Comment: I get an index out of bounds error for the very last line of code... Any ideas?